# its about grails programing how to pass multiple values from gsp page to javascript

Tags: javascript, grails

How can we pass the value of radio button and a domain value from gsp template page to java script function so that we can compare these two values and if the value matches we will dispaly the result. I have written all the javascript codes.The javascript code works when the function is with no parameters, but as soon as I pass the parameters it doesn't respond. My code is written in gsp code

```
<input type="radio" name="ans" onclick="checkans(${question.correct}, ${question.a})" class="form-control" style="width: 25px">
```

Question holds the value of question domain and it contains all the chosen options,correct answer.

javascript code

```
function checkans(check,correct){
    if(check.contains(correct)){    
        alert("your answer is correct");
    }else{
        alert("your answer is not correct");    
    }
}
```

but my javascript code is not responding

Comment: what do you mean by "not responding"? any errors in JS-console?

Answer (score 0):

You don't put the ' ( apice ) in the gsp,
try this:

```
<input type="radio" name="ans" onclick="checkans('${question.correct}', '${question.a}')" class="form-control" style="width: 25px">
```

It should work